# UIImageView not rotating correctly?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimageview

I have a UIScrollView inside a UIViewController. It has scrolling and zooming enabled. It contains a UIImageView and when the user rotates the device, the idea is that the image stays centered. The problem is, when the device is rotated, it actually appears off to the left instead of center, where it should be staying. Here is the code I'm using. Set frame is called when the UIScrollView rotates:

```
-(void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame {

    float previousWidth = self.frame.size.width;
    float newWidth = frame.size.width;

    [super setFrame:frame];
    self.imageView.center = CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width / 2, self.bounds.size.height / 2);

    [self setupScales];

    self.zoomScale = self.zoomScale * (newWidth / previousWidth);
}
```

Comment: None of these solutions seem to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following layoutsubviews method in my subclass of uiscrollview:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    if ([[self subviews] count] == 0) {
        return;
    }

    // center the image as it becomes smaller than the size of the screen
    CGSize boundsSize = self.bounds.size;
    CGRect frameToCenter = ((UIView*)[[self subviews] objectAtIndex:0]).frame;

    // center horizontally
    if (frameToCenter.size.width < boundsSize.width)
        frameToCenter.origin.x = (boundsSize.width - frameToCenter.size.width) / 2;
    else
        frameToCenter.origin.x = 0;

    // center vertically
    if (frameToCenter.size.height < boundsSize.height)
        frameToCenter.origin.y = ((boundsSize.height - frameToCenter.size.height) / 2);
    else
        frameToCenter.origin.y = 0;

    ((UIView*)[[self subviews] objectAtIndex:0]).frame = frameToCenter;
}
```

Comment: This code looks good, but it doesn't recognise the centeringYOffset variable, and I don't know what that could be either.

Comment: Ah yeah. Sorry. It's just a property on the subclass that can be set optionally if I want to center things higher or lower. You can probably just remove that bit.

Answer (score 0):

You probably also need to set the `contentOffset` property of the scroll view

Answer (score 0):

If scrollview resizes with orientation change, try this

```
self.imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
```